# How to find the maximum value in an ADT stack of integers in an array

Tags: c++, stack

Is there a function for array based stacks that allow you to find the maximum value in a stack of integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.  If you can access your stack as an array, you can use [**`std::max_element`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) to find the largest value in an array.  If you can only access the `top` element in the stack, then you simply have to pop each element to find the largest value.

Answer (score 0):

Given the operations Stack allow, you need to pop all the elements to find the maximum.
It doesn't provide a straight forward way.